# when i open my project in chrome browser the camera doesn't work but it works fine in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, camera

when i open my project in chrome browser the camera doesn't work but it works fine in firefox browser. How can I solve this problem? that is, in my project, I need to scan the qrcode through the camera, and it should work in any browser.

[image]

It's in chrome

[image]

It's in firefox

This my JS code

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
      const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
      const modal_open_btn = document.querySelector("#open-scan-btn");
      const modal_close_btn = document.querySelector(".btn-close");
      // Instascan library to handle QR code scanning
      const scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
        video: document.getElementById("qr-video"),
      });

      // Callback function when QR code is scanned
      scanner.addListener("scan", function (content) {
        // alert("QR Code content: " + content);
        
        // Do something with the scanned content (e.g., send it to the server)
        input.value = content;

        scanner.stop();
        modal_close_btn.click();
      });

      modal_open_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Open the camera and start scanning when the page is loaded
        Instascan.Camera.getCameras()
          .then((cameras) => {
            if (cameras.length > 0) {
              scanner.start(cameras[0]);
            } else {
              console.error("No cameras found.");
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });

      modal_close_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Stop scanning and close the camera when the close button is clicked
        scanner.stop();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Permissions-Policy header provides a mechanism to allow and deny the use of browser features in a document or within any iframe elements in the document.

camera
Controls whether the current document is allowed to use video input devices. When this policy is disabled, the Promise returned by getUserMedia() will reject with a NotAllowedError DOMException.

Also check this [I got answer from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy)